# I try to use MAP container to map resources, Now the RESOURCEFILE is getting alll Info. Why

Tags: c++, winapi

All the info in ResourcesMap  is broken up when comes to directories and filenames. I can not figure it out. when step thru it I can see no errors. But when check the info in ResourcesMap it all messed up.

It looks like the copy process is failing some how?

This is a Recursive Function That map a resource name to file structure.

```
struct RESOURCE {
    char Name[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
    int Level = 0;
    bool operator<(const RESOURCE& other) const
    {
    //write your compare function here...
    return (strcmp(Name, other.Name) < 0);
}

};


struct RESOURCEFILE {
char FileName[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
DWORD ATTRIBUTE = 0;
};

map <RESOURCE, RESOURCEFILE> ResourcesMap;


void PolulateResources(HWND hDlg , RESOURCE Resource, RESOURCEFILE File) {
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
wchar_t FileName[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
mbstowcs(FileName, File.FileName, MAX_PATH);
hFind = FindFirstFile(FileName, &ffd);
do {
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind) {
        switch (ffd.dwFileAttributes) {
        case FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY: {
            char temp[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
            wcstombs(temp, ffd.cFileName, MAX_PATH);
            File.ATTRIBUTE = ffd.dwFileAttributes;
            if (strcmp(temp, ".") != 0 && strcmp(temp, "..") != 0) {
                strcpy(Resource.Name, temp);
                AddItemToTree(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_TREE1), temp, Resource.Level, g_nOpen, g_nClosed);
                File.FileName[strlen(File.FileName) - 1] = NULL;
                strcat(File.FileName, temp);
                ResourcesMap[Resource] = File;
                strcat(File.FileName, "\\*");
                int SaveLevel = Resource.Level++;
                PolulateResources(hDlg, Resource, File);
                File.FileName[strlen(File.FileName) - strlen(temp) - 1] = NULL;
                Resource.Level = SaveLevel;
            }
        }break;
        case FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL:
        case FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE:
        case FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY:
        case FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN: {
            //Resource->Level++;
            char temp[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
            wcstombs(temp, ffd.cFileName, MAX_PATH);
            File.ATTRIBUTE = ffd.dwFileAttributes;
            strcpy(Resource.Name, temp);
            if (strstr(File.FileName, "\\*") != NULL) {
                File.FileName[strlen(File.FileName) - 1] = NULL;
                strcat(File.FileName, temp);
                ResourcesMap[Resource] = File;
                File.FileName[strlen(File.FileName) - strlen(temp)] = NULL;
                strcat(File.FileName, "*");
            }
            else {
                ResourcesMap[Resource] = File;
            }
            AddItemToTree(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_TREE1), temp, Resource.Level, g_nDocument, g_nOpen);
        }break;
        }

    }
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string` as soon as possible in your function?  As soon as this line is executed `wcstombs(temp, ffd.cFileName, MAX_PATH);`, you should be turning `temp` into a `std::string` and use that instead of all of that `strcat`, `strlen`, etc. stuff later on.

Comment: I don't know that why I am asking you guy. all so it works. all but the info in ResourcesMap.

Comment: *But when check the info in ResourcesMap it all messed up* -- "all messed up" is not a good description.  Exactly what is meant by "all messed up"?  Second, post a [mcve].

Comment: All messed up I mean File info does not keep. When I look at ResourcesMap some of directories are trunked FileName. It should have the full path in the ResourcesMap.

Comment: `RESOURCEFILE File` -- You should be passing by reference, not by value.  If your goal was to see `File` with updated results, passing by value as you're doing now isn't going to work.

Comment: File attributes are bits, you can't use a switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf()` converting `WCHAR*` to `char*`.

```
sprintf(File.ATTRIBUTE, "%ws", ffd.dwFileAttributes);
```

And the file attributes are bits, you should use `&`, juat like this:
`wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`

This function can find all files in the directory. It will printf complete path of file. You need to add the map in the right place. The parameters of funtion alse need to be changed.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<map>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
WCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH];

BOOL IsRoot(LPCTSTR lpszPath)
{
    WCHAR szRoot[10] = {0};
    wsprintf(szRoot, L"%c:\\", lpszPath);
    wprintf(L"\n");
    return (lstrcmp(szRoot, lpszPath) == 0);
}

void FindInAll(LPCTSTR lpszPath)
{
    TCHAR szFind[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    lstrcpy(szFind, lpszPath); //use lstrcpy
    if (!IsRoot(szFind))
        lstrcat(szFind, L"\\");
    lstrcat(szFind, L"*.*"); //find all files

    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(szFind, &wfd);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        return;
    do
    {
        if (wfd.cFileName[0] == '.')
            continue; //ignore the "." and ".."
        if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            //add here
            wsprintf(szFile, L"%s\\%s", lpszPath, wfd.cFileName);
            wprintf(szFile);
            FindInAll(szFile); //If find a dirctory
        }
        else if(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
        {   
            //add here
            wprintf(L"%ws\n", szFile); 
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &wfd));

    FindClose(hFind); //close handle
}

int main()
{
    FindInAll(L"D:\\Demo");
    return 0;
}
```